# Long text inside/outside the Venn diagram

Tags: diagrams, tikz-styles, text-decorations

I need to draw a Venn diagram with long text inside sectors. My attempt is borrowed from an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (2.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(60:2.5cm) circle (2.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2.5cm) circle (2.5cm)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(3cm,-1.5cm)}, fill opacity=0.25]
        \fill[red] \firstcircle;
        \fill[green] \secondcircle;
        \fill[blue] \thirdcircle;
        \draw \firstcircle node[below] {$Word_1$};
        \draw \secondcircle node[above] {$Word_2$};
        \draw \thirdcircle node[below] {$Word_3$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The exected result is:

[image]

I hope that the words (Word_1, Word_2, Word_3) can be placed along the border of the circles. But what to do if there is not enough space for text (for the cases Word_12, Word_13, Word_23 and especially for Word_123). The text size cannot be changed. For instance, one can move signatures outside of small sectors.

**Question.** Are there tools for text placement automations?

Comment: You can place letters [along a path](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf.decorations.text). And a circle (or an arc of 360°) can be such a path.

Answer (score 2):

You can place longer text outside, like so:
[image]

I left most problems from said code with some slight adaptations:

- the way it's done, the text will be almost invisible
- the shift after the scope statement doesn't seem to be useful
- (0,0) is where you'll find "Word_1" ... better would be in the very center of all intersections
- just put some node with long text outside
- draw a line to indicate, which field you mean
- for development, class `standalone` is better

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

%\pagestyle{empty}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (2.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(60:2.5cm) circle (2.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2.5cm) circle (2.5cm)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.25]
        \fill[red] \firstcircle;
        \fill[green] \secondcircle;
        \fill[blue] \thirdcircle;
%        \draw \firstcircle node[below] {$Word_1$};
        \draw \secondcircle node[above] {$Word_2$};
%        \draw \thirdcircle node[below] {$Word_3$};
    \end{scope}
    
    % ~~~ making text readable again ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw \firstcircle node[shift=(220:13mm)] {$Word_1$ !};
%   \draw \secondcircle node[above] {$Word_2$};
    \draw \thirdcircle node[below] {$Word_3$};

    % ~~~ putting some label outside ~~~~~
    \node[align=left] (A) at (-4,3) 
        {Here's some longer text\\with some breaks};
    
    % ~~~ connector, with some options, e.g. using polar coordinates for anchor
    \draw[dashed,blue,-{Circle[]}] (A.220) -- (0,1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```